# Не работает окно предпросмотра Xamarin.Forms

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, установка, java

При запуске инструмента вылезает окно с ошибкой:

```
Для средства предварительного просмотра требуется 64-разрядная версия Oracle Java JDK 8 (1.8) или более поздняя. 
Установите ее, а затем задайте расположение пакета Java Development Kit в меню "Средства" -> "Параметры" -> "Xamarin" -> "Параметры Android". 
Обратите внимание на то, что для установки 64-разрядного пакета JDK требуется 64-разрядная версия Windows (см. также статью по адресу https://support.microsoft.com/help/827218).
```

Но проблема в том что, у меня и так x64 java, которая уже определена по рекомендуемому пути
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И windows у меня x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переустановкой Windows

Comment: может стоило сначала JDK переустановить попробовать?

Comment: @Grundy переустанавливал, не помогло